# Common reference string in NIZK

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I want to ask that does the common reference string in NIZK have to be 
random?

Or can it be anything?

Answer (score 5):

The common reference string in NIZK does not have to be *uniformly distributed*.

It is to be sampled from whatever distribution the NIZK protocol specifies.

However, the common *random* string in NIZK *does* have to be uniformly distributed,

and the setup strings in [NIZK](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/85.pdf) also have to be uniformly distributed.